# Изменение LayoutParams view в случае изменения размера родителя

Tags: android, view

Есть `ImageView`. Его параметры: left/topMargin и width/height я выставляю в runtime в зависимости от размера родителя. К примеру, после действия юзера (пускай клик), я помещаю в ImageView некоторую картинку, [смотрю](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth()) какие размеры у родителя и уже задаю непосредственно для ImageView параметры:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
p.leftMargin = (int) ((pw - lw) / 2f);
_topMargin = (int) ((ph - lh) / 2f);
lp.topMargin = _topMargin;
lp.width = lw;
lp.height = lh;
requestLayout();
```

Всё работает. Но размеры родителя могут измениться. У меня это происходит только в одном случае, когда меняем ориентацию девайса. Ловить [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) бесполезно, т.к. размеры у родителя будут старые (как до поворота). Ловлю тогда у родителя [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), уже знаю новые его размеры, но проблема. Если я попытаюсь менять ImageView в этом случае (из этого эвента), никакого эффекта, остаются старые положения картинки.

Тогда делаю как: в onSizeChanged родителя просто запускаю тред, где жду небольшое время и меняю параметры - они меняются.

Когда происходит событие `onConfigurationChanged`, я подписываюсь на событие `ViewTreeObserver::addOnGlobalLayoutListener`. Здесь уже нормально меняются параметры.
Главное после не забыть от этого же события отписаться.